# A simple within range function

Tags: r, function

I am trying to make a simple function that, when you put in three numbers - x - any numeric variable, and y and z - the min and max of a range
the function will return a message telling you if the number is in range or not. I should use the specific formulation of `x % in range` within the function

```
inrange = function(x, y, z){
range = y:z
if (x % in range)
   print("number is in range")
   else print("number is not in range")
}
```

When I try this code I am returned with an error that it is not recognizing the end bracket.  Why is this?

Comment: You may need to use `if (x %in% range)` instead of `x % in range`

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way instead of just checking the bounds directly with <= and >=.

Comment: ... and returning a `TRUE`/`FALSE` value might be more useful than printing a message ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized version that works not just with sequence with a step function of 1. It returns the indices of x that are within the range

```
inrange <- function(x, y, z) {
    y <- rep(y, length=length(x)) # To fix partial recycling of y/z
    (x>=pmin(y,z)) * (x<=pmax(y,z))
}
```

This enables you to do stuff like:

```
> inrange(1:10, 3, 7)
 [1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: This is almost the same as the `between()` and `inrange()` functions from the `data.table` package.